# Storyboard simple constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I am really struggling with this simple thing every time I choose to work with storyboard.

I have only 2 containers, one as a toolbar and one as a container for VC.

It looks like this:

[image]

The only thing I want, is to keep this simple structure to look the same for both `iPhone 7/8` and `7/8 plus`. Which means same aspect ratio to get a toolbar.

I have tried to set 0 spaces for top/left/right on the top container, and bottom/left/right on the bottom container.

At that point, anything I do, will make this work only for iphone 8+.

1. Tried to set both sizes by checking the width/height box
2. Tried to instead, set the aspect ration by checking the box
3. Tried to set a 0 spacing between them.

Anything, anything I do, will make it get messy on iPhone 7/8.

How do you do such a simple thing?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "Which means same aspect ratio to get a toolbar."?

Comment: Do you expect the toolbar view to always have the same height? Or do you want it's height to vary depending on the device height? Or do you want some different logic?

Comment: can you post simulator screenshots in 7 and 8 ?

Comment: I just want to keep this aspect ration between them, its so simple and yet Apple made this so hard !

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "aspect ration between them". Do you mean that the toolbar always takes 1/10th of the screen's height and the top view 9/10th? Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want what you say in the comments you have to set up the following constraints:

```
1. top view (leading, top & trailing) to superview = 0
2. bottom view (leading, bottom & trailing) to superview = 0
3. top view (bottom) to bottom view (top) = 0
4. bottom view (height) equal to (super)view (height) with a multiplier of 1:10 (or whatever ratio you want it to be)
```

[image: iphone7]
[image: iphone7plus]

By the way I think the way you communicate with people who are trying to help ("Do you know what a toolbar means?") is very disrespecting. You should think about it and make your purposes more clear in future questions...

Comment: How do you do 3 and 4 ??

Comment: 3: ctrl drag from the top view to the bottom view and choose "vertical spacing" - set its constant to 0.
4: ctrl drag from the bottom view to the superview and choose "equal heights" - set its multiplier to the ratio you expect.

Comment: thanks, number 4 I am not able to drag to superview, because the whole superview is cover by both of them. How would you do that ?

Comment: Use the document outline (window on the left of the interface builder).

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution, it makes everything even more messy and say there are many missing constrains, but I will accept it anyway , thank you.

Comment: You should not accept and answer that does not answer your question. Although I am pretty sure that you are doing something wrong since in my case it works perfectly.

Comment: There are a lot of errors messages with your constrains, there is not much where to be wrong here, it just gives a lot of constrains errors on run time.

Comment: Your example is not with a container view which loads another view controller, which means you do something else anyway, when you load a VC into it, you get a complex relationship, and I for example keep reading the view.frame.height of the top container, as the full screen height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163535/discussion-between-andre-slotta-and-curnelious).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the same aspect ratio between the views, select both views and add the "equal Height" constraint. Set a multiplier that match the ratio that you want